# Can i use JQuery in by blog created on blogspot: www.DotNetAcademy.blogspot.com

Tags: jquery, blogs

I have got a blog Url: www.DotNetAcademy.Blogspot.com please tell me, how can i use JQuery in that blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just go to your blogger dashboard->Layout->Edit HTML

and add

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

and you can start using it.

Comment: Can't really say more than that. Anything you want to do in particular?